# Flutter, How handle state when awaiting for firebase data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

`checkBorrowerAlreadyExists()` Function checks if a user input name already exists in firebase data and returns a bool. I am using this function in an if condition after `onPressed` of a button, I am providing user input as an argument to the function in if condition and display the snackbar based on the bool value. This works perfectly fine when firebase already has data, But initially when the user register and opens the app, firebase won't have any data to check if name already exists and nothing happens on the screen.

I used else condition to return false if no data, move on and add input in firebase, but didn't work. I also tried using the bool in different way but didn't work. How do I solve this.

```
  checkBorrowerAlreadyExists(String textfieldname) async {
    await for (var snapshots in _firestorem
        .collection('lender')
        .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .collection('borrowers')
        .snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapshots.docs) {
        bool isThere;
        if (message.data().containsValue(textfieldname)) {
          return isThere = true;
        } else {
          return isThere = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
                              onPressed: () async {
                                if (borrowerNameController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  Get.snackbar(
                                      'Error:', "Borrower Name can't be empty",
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                                } else if (await checkBorrowerAlreadyExists(
                                    borrowerNameController.text)) {
                                  Get.snackbar('Error',
                                      'Borrower Name alread exists, Enter new name',
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                                } else{ upload data in firebase}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `await` in the `build` method, as there's no way to hold up rendering.

The solution is actually in the return type of your function, which you left implicit not. If you make the return type explicit, it is:

```
Future<bool> checkBorrowerAlreadyExists(String textfieldname) async {
  ...
```

Since this returns a `Future`, you need to use a `FutureBuilder` in your `build` method to render the boolean value (and to determine what to render until that value is available).

So something like:

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (borrowerNameController.text.isEmpty) {
    Get.snackbar('Error:', "Borrower Name can't be empty", backgroundColor: Colors.red);
 } 
 else {
   return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: checkBorrowerAlreadyExists(), 
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(borrowerNameController.text)
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
        } else {
          return Text('Awaiting result...'),
        }
      },
    ),
```

I recommend checking out the documentation on [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and Flutter's codelab on [asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).